# Multiple redirect in the login (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, apache-tiles

**I am trying to achieve:**

After session timeout the user is redirected to the login page and when he login again he should be redirected to the original url that the user entered.

**The problem is:**

Multiple redirects are happening in the login page. So, if I type `http://localhost:8080/app-web/login` in the browser then Fiddler shows me the following:

1. 200 /app-web/login
2. 302 /app-web/0
3. 302 /app-web/0/
4. 200 /app-web/login

As a result, after login it is redirecting me to /app-web/0/

I am using apache tiles. Any help will be appreciated and let me know if you need more info about the configuration.

**EDIT**

Here are few config:

```
<http auto-config="true" 
        use-expressions="true" 
        disable-url-rewriting="true"
        entry-point-ref="ajaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="postSuccessAuthHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="postFailureAuthHandler"   
            login-page="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" 
            default-target-url="/pin"/>
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/resetForgotPassword" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>
```

The login view:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login"/>
```

Tiles:

```
<definition  name="login" extends="NoNav.Template" >
        <put-attribute name="NoNavMainBodyContainer" value="LoginMainBodyContainer.Template" cascade="true" />
    </definition>
```

Comment: show the class and configuration as to how the redirection is done.

Comment: I cannot figure out how the redirection happens but I added few config